# How to communicate directly to external client with IP and port

Tags: java, sockets, firewall, nat, stun

I made a game writen in JAVA. It has two players, one will be the server.

A computer creates the game and serves it.
Another computer (outside) needs to connect to the server using its IP and port.
When they connect, the game starts and the client player send its moves to the server, the moves are computed there and the new client and server positions in the game map are returned and updated.

The problem is: when I create the game localy, the server and client in the same router, using local IP, the game starts successfuly. But when I create the game and try to connect from external computer, the server isn't found.

I read a bit and the problem is probably the computer firewall or router's NAT (what I didn't understand too much). Well, I found something called STUN, there say that it bypass firewall and router blocking using a STUN server, and found a list of free STUN servers ([here](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933)) too. But I don't know what to do with it. The STUN servers will enable the server and client communication?

It's possible, without buying any online service, and with the two players computers (the server player and client player), make successfuly connection without portfoward or firewall disabling?

I want to share my game, but I can't ask to every player disable their firewall to play. =/

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding/firewall only on server side. Clients do not need to do anything special.

Comment: This is a question about networks and network configuration, not programming.  It is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

For direct (peer-to-peer) communication if you want to place server anywhere in network (especially behind NAT) you need to use black-magic technics known as "NAT Traversal".

Many details about this is described in article [Peer-to-Peer Communication Across Network Address Translators](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/). You need "TCP Hole Punching" section from there.

Anyway NAT traversal doesn't work in all cases (there are always exceptions when NAT works not as expected by traversal algorithm). So the best way to solve all problems is to place dedicated server somewhere with public IP address and use it.